# Javascript ASP.Net Inline Code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 3 and Javascript/JQuery. So I have in the main body of one of my views:

```
<script src="myfile.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var myVar = doSomething("string to manipulate");
    });
</script>
```

So here, I have an external file, loaded up in the body of the view. And `doSomething()` is a function that resides in the external `.js` file.

When I run this view chrome's console shows an error saying that it could not find the definition for `doSomething()` i.e. the function doesn't exist!

Is this because `$(function () {})` is the equivalent of `$(this).ready(function {})` so loads this up before the external js file? I'm not sure though, any help on this would be great!

Comment: The loading of the `<script src="myfilej.s">` is blocking, so the second `<script>` block won't execute until the browser finishes retrieving it. Are you sure `myfile.js` is loaded properly?

Comment: That should not be a issue as the script loads in a sequential order.. Wondering  if the `MIME` type has to do anything with it.. It should not be a  issue if DOC type is HTML5 , but might be a browser specific issue if the `MIME` type is not included

Comment: ahhhh okay, that is exactly what I thought! strange problem then!

Comment: @Sushanth-- they are all `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Is `myfile.js` very big? Like would you be able to post it? Or are you 100% sure that `doSomething` is declared globally?

Comment: Ya right.. But I do  not see it on the script tag ... That was my reasoning

Comment: @Ian right, so I looked on chrome again, clicked on the resource it had loaded up, and it was the old version, so i will have to flush the cache!!! Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @Sushanth-- right, thats cool, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was not in my code, it was due to chrome using an old cached file. So I cleared browsing data, hosted app data, cache (cache on it's own wasn't enough) and it has all started working. Thanks for the help contributors!!